# Limiting a .bat file to only 200 lines in txt file

Tags: batch-file

I have this .bat file and I wanted to limit it to only 200 lines in gmname.txt. Basically, when this .bat file is ran for each line, say I have 300 lines in gnmname.txt I want to start the UpMe.bat for only 200.  I know this should be simple but any help is appreciated.

```
for /f "tokens=1" %%k in (gmname.txt) do start /MIN UpMe.bat %%k
```

Comment: Please **do not** add a tagline or signature to your posts or they will be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you want to process a command for X amount of lines of a textfile? then here is the code:

```
@Echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Set /A "Limit=200"

for /F "Usebackq tokens=1" %%k in (
    "gmname.txt"
) do (
    Set /A "Line+=1"
    If !LINE! LEQ !LIMIT! (start /MIN UpMe.bat %%k)
)

Pause&Exit
```

Answer (score 0):

http://ss64.com/nt/for.html shows how to run a code block for each line of the input file

```
SET count=1
 for /f "tokens=1" %%k in (gmname.txt) do (
 echo %count% : %%k
 set /a count+=1 )
```

you can use that kind of approach and adapt it to exit the batch file when `count` reaches over 200

Failing that, you could call a subroutine instead of using a code block, this link shows how
http://ss64.com/nt/call.html

Comment: This doesn't work. Inside a code block you need `delayed expansion`  and `!variables!`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%k in ('findstr /n $ gmname.txt') do if %%k leq 200 start /MIN UpMe.bat %%l
```

There shouldn't be empty lines in `gmname.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

This should launch upme.bat if "gmname.txt" has more than 200 lines.

```
@echo off
for /f %%a in ('find /c /v "" ^< "gmname.txt" ') do if %%a GTR 200 call upme.bat
```